# Converting matrix to vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have the following:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 7, byrow = T)

> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0
```

When I try to convert `a` to a vector with:

```
b <-  split(a, rep(1:nrow(a), each = ncol(a)))

> b
$`1`
[1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 # suppose to be 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

$`2`
[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 # suppose to be 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

I did not get the expected output of `1100000` and `0101100`. It looked like the vector is filled by column first. How can I do the opposite?

Comment: Also `split.default(a, 1:nrow(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` by `row`

```
split(a, row(a))
```

Or use the OP's method

```
split(a, rep(1:nrow(a), ncol(a)))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

#$`2`
#[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

NOTE: Make sure to not use `each`, instead use `times` as `matrix`, `data.frame` etc does columnwise split